# SQL: Select and order first the rows that match specific ids and specific types

Tags: php, sql, sorting

I have the following table:

```
id name type
-- ---- -----
1  Joe  H
1  Zoe  F
2  Ken  F
2  Ben  H
3  Lime H
4  Fine F
5  Lima F
5  Sima H
```

I want to select first the rows that match:

```
id: 5 & type: H

id: 2 & type: F

id: 3 & type: H
```

And after them the rest ordered by id ASC.

So the final result should be:

```
id name type
-- ---- -----
5  Sima H
2  Ken  F
3  Lime H
1  Joe  H
1  Zoe  F
2  Ben  H
4  Fine F
5  Lima F
```

I just couldn't find how to show first specific rows sorted by more than one value. I use PHP and MySqli if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: this is a pain to do in mysql, you might as well just select all the rows, and manipulate in PHP, since you're selecting them all anyway.

Comment: Are you sure it would be easier to do in PHP?
And can you send me an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order with a case statement:

```
select * from table
order by
    case 
        when id = 5 and type = 'H' then 0
        when id = 2 and type = 'F' then 1
        when id = 3 and type = 'H' then 2
        else 3
    end, id, name
```

Comment: Is this the easiest and fastest way to do so?

Comment: @Ido It's the easiest way I know and it is correct. Be careful with using `UNION` to get a specific order. While you will get the correct results most of the time it is actually not guaranteed if the outer query does not contain an `ORDER BY`. See "Use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: Thanks! It is also the fastest way for big tables, right?

Comment: @Ido the fastest way is to add another column specifying the order. but w/o adding a column I believe this is the fastest way

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for MySQL I'll give you a MySQL answer.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = 5 AND `type` = "H" ORDER BY id ASC) t
   UNION
(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = 2 AND `type` = "F" ORDER BY id ASC)
    UNION
(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = 3 AND `type` = "H" ORDER BY id ASC)
    UNION
(SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY id ASC);
```

The result

```
+------+------+------+
| id   | name | type |
+------+------+------+
|    5 | Sima | H    |
|    2 | Ken  | F    |
|    3 | Lime | H    |
|    1 | Joe  | H    |
|    1 | Zoe  | F    |
|    2 | Ben  | H    |
|    4 | Fine | F    |
|    5 | Lima | F    |
+------+------+------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Isn't it significantly slower than FuzzyTree's answer since it searches each time the whole table?

Comment: yeah. it doesnt search the whole table each time if you got an index on id and type. speed wasnt specified to be an issue. i assumed it's a small dataset, which is why i suggested using PHP at first. if you have a gigantic table, then your query will eat your memory.